# Matching values between dictionaries

Tags: python

I wrote a Python script for Maya that first creates one dictionary of all shaders in the scene and then sorting them into two dictionaries. One for unique shaders and one for duplicated shaders.
The dictionary has the shader name(which is unique) as key and then the value is the name of the color texture that is connected. So if two shaders have the same texture file, the last one is added to the duplicated shaders dictionary.

The thing I'm wondering about is the code for loooping through the duplicated shaders and then switching them out for the unique shaders, effectively deleting all duplicated shaders in the scene.

The way I have it working right now is that I loop through the duplicated shaders by key and inside this loop, I loop through the unique shaders with key. If there's a match between the two. That is if the values are the same, that means they use the same texture. This works fine, but I'm wondering if there's a better approach than using nested loops like this. I could look for the key by value as it is unique for the elements in the unique dictionary, but that seems like as much effort for the execution time as my approach with nested loops.

Comment: Why not just check the key on the unique dictionary directly?

Comment: post your code please, http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thanks. Not sure how I would go about checking the key on the unique dictionary directly. As I said, the key is the name of the shader and it doesn't exist in any form in duplicate dictionary.

Comment: I'll post the code when I'm back home

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but here's my code

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/16029672/dictionaries.txt